# Month to month data comparison

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to create a formula in Crystal Reports using the below data that will calculate the difference of DxLoaded in the current RunDt minus the previous month RunDt for each of the two Data Sources.  Each month a new RunDt will be populated.  When the report is refreshed I need to have the formula calculate using the most current RunDt comparing it to the previous RunDt for each Data Source.

For example, I would like to calculate 5,491,932 for the 1203 RunDt minus 3,830,842 for the 1202 RunDt.  Then have the formula do that for each Data Source that might be populated.  There will also be service year of 2012 for the same Data Source and would like 2011 compared only with 2011 and 2012 with 2012.  I've tried using the previous function but haven't had luck with obtaining the correct results.

```
Yr             Data_Source  RunDt_YYMM      DxLoaded   
2011           ABS          1203            5,491,932  
2011           ABS          1202            3,830,842  
2011           IALT         1203            9,193,144  
2011           IALT         1202            6,578,678  
2012           ABS          1203            1,837,900  
2012           ABS          1202            1,083,124  
2012           IALT         1203            4,223,111  
2012           IALT         1202            2,985,543
```

Any help of suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the text of each of the formulas that you have built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the output to appear in the order given in the question, and that you want the difference to appear next to the most recent `RunDt_YYMM` value for the data source and year:

- Explicitly sort the dataset in the order required - ie. `Yr` ascending, `Data_Source` ascending, `RunDt_YYMM` **descending**. (It should be possible to do this either in the query or in the Crystal Record Sort expert.)
- Enter a formula like the following (amend to match your table name):

```
if NextIsNull ({SummaryTable.Yr}) then 0 else
if {SummaryTable.Data_Source}=Next({SummaryTable.Data_Source}) and
   {SummaryTable.Yr}=Next({SummaryTable.Yr})
then {SummaryTable.DxLoaded} - Next({SummaryTable.DxLoaded})
```

- Drag and drop the new formula from the Field Explorer into the report detail section, next to the `DxLoaded` field.

Comment: Thank you Mark, your suggestion worked.  The only other question I have is what if I want to only display the most current RunDt_YYMM?  When I tried to display only 1203 on the report the formula turned to zeros.  Any way to still have the formula function when the previous RunDt is not displayed on the report itself?  I happen to do a Record Selection Formula, {HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} = cStr(currentdate,'yyMM'), and that's when the values turned to zero.  I will need to try to make this work when only showing current RunDt.

Comment: You would need to do: `{HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} = cStr(currentdate,'yyMM') or {HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} = cStr(dateadd('m',-1,currentdate),'yyMM')` then if you are displaying your fields in the detail section you will need to conditionally suppress the section using `{HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} <> cStr(currentdate,'yyMM')`- though obviously i still prefer my approach :)

Comment: @LaTrishaRoman: As Lee explained, you would need to select both the current and previous YYMM, then suppress the output from the previous YYMM - Crystal can only perform calculations on data it has retrieved.

Comment: Thanks so much guys!!  I'm able to do what I need to based on your suggestions.  =)  One last thing.  How can I summarize the results.  It's not letting me insert summary, do a running total or sum in a formula. Is a separate formula needed at this point?

Comment: @LaTrishaRoman: Yes - assuming your difference formula was called `RunDateDifference`, create a new formula as `global numberVar SDD := SDD+{@RunDateDifference}` then drop your new formula into the detail section and your report footer section. (You may want to suppress it in your detail section.)

Comment: @MarkBannister Appreciate your help !  It worked out exactly the way I needed it to!

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to get bogged down with this sort of problem. The trick is to sort the data out in the query by joining the table to itself using the rundt column. You can either do this in crystal using a custom command or what I prefer to do is create a view or stored procedure in SQL. For example:

```
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP
FROM ( 
SELECT 2011 Yr, 'ABS' Data_Source, '1203' RunDt_YYMM, 5491932 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2011 Yr, 'ABS' Data_Source, '1202' RunDt_YYMM, 3830842 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2011 Yr, 'IALT' Data_Source, '1203' RunDt_YYMM, 9193144 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2011 Yr, 'IALT' Data_Source, '1202' RunDt_YYMM, 6578678 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2012 Yr, 'ABS' Data_Source, '1203' RunDt_YYMM, 1837900 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2012 Yr, 'ABS' Data_Source, '1202' RunDt_YYMM, 1083124 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2012 Yr, 'IALT' Data_Source, '1203' RunDt_YYMM, 4223111 DxLoaded
UNION SELECT 2012 Yr, 'IALT' Data_Source, '1202' RunDt_YYMM, 2985543 DxLoaded
) A

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

SELECT 
 a.Yr, a.Data_Source, a.RunDT_YYMM, a.DxLoaded, b.DxLoaded PrevDxLoaded
FROM 
 #TEMP a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 #TEMP b
ON 
 b.Yr = a.Yr 
AND 
 b.Data_Source = a.Data_Source 
AND 
 b.RunDT_YYMM = CASE WHEN RIGHT(a.RunDT_YYMM,2) = '01' THEN  
  CAST(CAST(a.RunDT_YYMM as INT) - 89 AS VARCHAR(4))
 ELSE 
  CAST(CAST(a.RunDT_YYMM as INT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(4))
 END
```

Result:

```
Yr      Data_Source   RunDT_YYMM DxLoaded   PrevDxLoaded
2011    ABS           1202       3830842    NULL
2011    ABS           1203       5491932    3830842
2011    IALT          1202       6578678    NULL
2011    IALT          1203       9193144    6578678
2012    ABS           1202       1083124    NULL
2012    ABS           1203       1837900    1083124
2012    IALT          1202       2985543    NULL
2012    IALT          1203       4223111    2985543
```